# Связка формы со слайдером

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Ребята подскажите как можно связать форму со слайдером?Чтобы в письме на почту приходили контактные данные из формы + имя из слайдера(в слайдере 4 фото менеджеров+их имена) из слайдера?

Comment: при отправке формы находить активный слайд и отправлять. Предоставьте код или хотя бы какой слайдер используете

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: слайдер использую свой,которые сделал. Форма Contact form 7. Сайта на Worpress.  l2banners (если можно скиньте свои контакты). Напишу вам как закончу со слайдером. Спасибо заранее.